# Python unit testing import problems

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import

I have a product with several features. At a high level, I'm trying to figure out how to structure my directories and do my imports such that all of the following are true.

1. The directory structure has a separate directory for each feature.
2. Each feature directory has a `src` directory that contains the code that will be deployed to the server.
3. Each feature directory has a `test` directory that contains the unit tests for the modules in the `src` folder.
4. We can use automatic test discovery from the `unittest` module.

For example, my `scifi` project has an `antigravity` feature and a `ftl` feature. The tree presently looks like this; when I started I had no `__init__.py` files.

```
~/Projects/scifi $ tree
.
├── antigravity
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── antigravity.py
│   │   ├── gravity.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── test
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_antigravity.py
└── ftl
    ├── ...
    └── ...
```

The antigravity module imports from gravity module

```
~/Projects/scifi $ cat antigravity/src/gravity.py 
def fall():
    return 9.8

~/Projects/scifi $ cat antigravity/src/antigravity.py
# absolute import
from gravity import fall

def fly():
    return -fall()
```

Now I write a test module and find that it cannot import the antigravity module to test it.

```
~/Projects/scifi $ cat antigravity/test/test_antigravity.py 
from antigravity.src.antigravity import fly
import unittest

class TestAntigravity(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_my_subtract_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(fly(), -9.8)

~/Projects/scifi $ python -m unittest
E
======================================================================
ERROR: antigravity.test.test_antigravity (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: antigravity.test.test_antigravity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "[~/Projects/scifi]/antigravity/test/test_antigravity.py", line 1, in <module>
    from antigravity.src.antigravity import fly
  File "[~/Projects/scifi]/antigravity/src/antigravity.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gravity import fall
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gravity'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

This is where I added the `__int__.py` files, and then got the same error. After that I made one small change to `antigravity.py` and ran my tests again

```
~/Projects/scifi $ cat antigravity/src/antigravity.py 
# relative import
from .gravity import fall

def fly():
    return -fall()

~/Projects/scifi $ python -m unittest
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Great, so now `antigravity` can import `gravity` for testing, but I soon find that the import fails any other time.

```
~/Projects/scifi $ python antigravity/src/antigravity.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "antigravity/src/antigravity.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .gravity import fall
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

So an absolute package reference gets me `ModuleNotFoundError` while testing and a relative package reference gets me an `ImportError` any other time. How do I get the import to work in both situations?

Here's a [copy of this example on Github](https://github.com/Adam-Hoelscher/scifi_testing) so that nobody has to copy/paste to get my example.

Comment: Which dir are you running your tests and your code from?

Comment: The top level directory of the product.

Comment: Have you tried adding that top level to the python path with something like `export PYTHONPATH=<the path of your top level>` that way python will treat that top level as a place to look for packages and the `__init__.py` files should then have a known parent package

Comment: Changing PYTHONPATH has no effect

Comment: Strange, I have built the same dir structure you have and can run both test and code with absolute or relative paths